# Create a link to file server and put it in a textbox

Tags: vb.net, directory, hyperlink

how can i create in vb.net a link to a local folder path? And how can i catch the link-click event to open the folder?

I want to put the link in a textbox.

Unfortunenately i only found examples for open a weblink...

many thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't put links in a `TextBox`. You can use a `RickTextBox` or a `LinkLabel`. Decide which one you want to use, research it, make an attempt and then, if it doesn't work, post a proper question with all the relevant information.

Comment: I tried to use the Rich text box. As i already mentioned, there are not many examples for a link to fileserver. Unfortunenately.

The following code append a link to my rich text box. It only works when it has website-Style (http:/....)

        'Dim hyperlinkText As String = "--> Link to temporary saved files"
        Dim hyperlinkText As String = "http:\\www.google.com"
       TB_Info.AppendText("{\cf1\ul " & hyperlinkText & "\cf0\ulnone}")

Comment: Another disadvantage is that all characters (\cf1\ul) are shown in the link.
However, here i have the link inside. With the TB_Info.LinkClicked Event i can react with process.start("explorer.exe","C:\temp\xyz")

@jmcilhinney do you have a few improvements for me?

Comment: Note that `File://` also identifies a protocol, not just `http://`. See the [LinkLabel.Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.linklabel.link) example on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to put it in a textbox? Sharing some code would be helpful as well.

My thought is that if you use a local path, the computer will think it needs to look on the local computer to locate the file. You may have to use ASP.net to help with this. I'd look up some info about how to use it in conjunction with VB but I have a hard time understanding why you'd ever need to put this information into a textbox. Textbox's are typically used to hold input for variables and calculations, etc. But maybe I'm not seeing what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

That's the purpose of my link in textbox. Afterwards, i think a simple label would have been sufficient. But now i solved the problem with the following code:

Append textbox with link:

```
    `enter code here`With TB_Info
        .AppendText(vbCrLf)
        Dim hyperlinkText As String = "File://Link_to_temporary_saved_files"
        .SelectionFont = New Font("Segoe UI", 11, FontStyle.Underline)
        .SelectionColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue
        .AppendText(hyperlinkText)
    End With
```

React on link-clicking-event:

```
`enter code here`Private Sub TB_Info_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As LinkClickedEventArgs) Handles TB_Info.LinkClicked


    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", famos_dataFolderPath)

End Sub
```

One mistake among others was that the file-link must be without free-spaces, so i used the character "_"